# my files wont stop saying 'waiting to upload'

Tags: icloud, filesystem

so ive been downloading sims4 mods for months on my macbook air and i went to download some more and for some reason all my files suddenly said "waiting to upload" or "upload" i don't understand why.i went onto my sims4 game and the previous mods are still there but not the new ones. when the "waiting to download" is'nt there all new mods work. i have so much storage space for icloud so whats going on? why are any downloaded files saying this?? i have re started my mac several times and re connected to two different wifi's but still nothing, its still saying the same

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Are you refering to iCloud Drive? Do other files upload to iCloud without a problem?  Does your internet access work fine?  Can you upload them from a different device to see if it's an iCloud or device problem?

Comment: Have you tried signing out and signing in again?